# mac sleeps/shutsdown leaves mail unmanaged

Tags: macos, email, sleep, shutdown, iphone

ideally a stupid question. the mac shutsdown or sleeps instead of acting like a server. i run apple mail on my mac using rules and read mail on my iphone. mail is not processed if it doesn’t go thru mac first. What am I missing? macbookpro macos 10 mumble iphone 8+ ios current. [copied from stackoverflow per suggestion]

Comment: You probably don't have server based rules.

Answer (score 0):

Rules defined in Mail.app on your Mac are executed locally only, so your Mac needs to be up and running to actually process them. There are several options to resolve this:

- You can leave your Mac up and running by going to **System Preferences** -> **Power Settings** and turn of sleep mode
- If you use iCloud for your mails you can actually login on icloud.com, open the webmail interface and define rules. These will only apply to mail send to your iCloud address though, and the rule set is limited compared to the one available in Mail.app, but for typical tasks like sorting mail into folders based on sender or subject they are good enough.

Comment: thank you so far. the mail.app rules do need to be run on the mac first. however the mac keeps sleeping or shutting down. how do I keep it alive? I do not use iCloud on purpose.

Comment: @elein See edit. Not sure about the english name of the preferences pan to use, it's the one with a light bulb.